# How do I toggle between two IDs of a HTML element with javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<div id = 'ONE' onclick = "change to id TWO" >One</div>
```

What I want is that every time I click that `div` it'll toggle between ID ONE and ID TWO, if it's on ID TWO and I click it, it switches to ID ONE and vice versa. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know what to do, I just got started learning javascript.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish with this? Maybe we can suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: Read documentations and start to do it on your own, when you stuck with any issues in the middle, come here post the code and ask for help. We cannot write the entire code for you when you didn't even try anything. Sorry.

Comment: Toggle what? Position, ids, text?

Comment: solved it. Please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is most easily accomplished with jQuery.

First thing that comes to my mind is setting a click counter to 0. If it's even, we will change the id to `red`, if it's odd, we change the id to `blue`.

```js
var clickCount = 0;

$("div").on("click", function() {
    clickCount++;
    $("div").attr("id", clickCount % 2 === 0 ? "blue" : "red");
});
```

```css
#red { color: red; }
#blue { color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>This is a div</div>
```

Here is the native JavaScript equivalent.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("my-div");
var clickCount = 0;

div.addEventListener("click", function() {
    clickCount++;
    div.setAttribute("id", clickCount % 2 === 0 ? "blue" : "red");
});
```

```css
#red { color: red; }
#blue { color: blue; }
```

```html
<div id="my-div">This is a div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
function changediv() {
    if (document.getElementById("one")) {
        document.getElementById("one").id = "two";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("two").id = "one";
    }
}
```

Then on your `div`

```
<div id = "one" onclick = "changediv()" >Your stuff</div>
```